# What's in Chrome's data?

Tags: internal-storage, chrome-for-android

I'm running stock 4.1.2 on a Wolfgang AT-AS43D4 (not rooted). According to *[DiskUsage](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage)*, I have about 755 MiB app storage in total, of which I have currently around 100 MiB free space left, so I try to keep the internal storage as empty as possible.

I see Chrome taking up 94.4 MiB, (134 MiB after [the latest update](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/67250/51314)) of which about 24.3 MiB is data (up to 28 MiB by now).

My question is twofold:

What is in there? What does Chrome keep there that's <del>almost</del> over 25 MB big?

How can I *selectively* clean that? I can delete the data wholesale, but I don't want to. Is there any other way? I tried various options in Chrome, but couldn't find anything useful.

---

Edited: a previous version of this question mentioned an `insufficient memory` error. This had little to do with the question; I was conflating RAM and app storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It contains:-

- Resource files for Chrome itself. These are really part of the app, but they're downloaded by Chrome itself so the APK doesn't need to contain all the resources for all locales, and to make them easier to update.
- Local storage for websites that use the HTML5 local storage feature. For some sites (e.g. Twitter) this can get quite large.
- All your preferences, just like any other app. This amounts to a few KB.

Answer (score 2):

Well, "insufficient memory" sounds like you're having problem with your memory(RAM), not your storage space.

DiskUsage is a very good tool, but it only checks disk space and not your memory(RAM) usage.

I just checked out the specs on your phone, and you have 512mb memory(RAM). That's 1/6 of what i have got on my phone, Samsung Galaxy note 3 with 3000mb memory(RAM).

I know it can be confusing with the terms when reviewers and everyone use memory, sdcard, storage and ram very loosely. I use the same terms people use on computers.

My chrome application is currently using 91mb of storagespace as "data". I believe that chrome is just storing pictures and tempfiles for the open webpages in data, along with your settings, passwords and so on. You can at any time go into the settings on your android menu, choose "applications", find "chrome" and delete data. Your Chome application will then act like you just installed it. You can try to see if this helps. and it might help for some time.

I think the main problem is that you don't have enough memory(RAM) on your device, and running a almost new os(4.1.2).

If you compare your phone with my previous phone, Samsung galaxy S2 as it was released in 2011 and has twice as much memory(1000mb RAM) as your phone. This phone came with Android 2.3. which does not require as much as newer versions.

I looked up on your os, Android 4.1.x, and the minimum requirements are as following:

> 7.6.1. Minimum Memory and Storage
>
> "Device implementations MUST have at
> least 340MB of memory available to the kernel and userspace. The 340MB
> MUST be in addition to any memory dedicated to hardware components
> such as radio, video, and so on that is not under the kernel's
> control."

*Source: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/no//compatibility/4.1/android-4.1-cdd.pdf*

This won't give you much left to other applications.

Well, i think that Chrome also have a share of the blame, as this is no lightweight browser. To solve the problem then I'd first try to set for another browser that is lighter. I would, for example, try "opera browser", which is designed to use as little data traffic as possible and to run on slow phones. The browser also has a feature that allows when you're phone is asking for a webpage, it will fetch the entire page onto Opera's servers and compress images before the webpage is sent to your phone. This means that the images are not displayed in full quality, but since the screen of a cell phone much smaller than on a pc, its just as well. Since the images is compressed, and use less data traffic, it will also use less space on the cellphone's storage-temp-space. Hopefully, this will solve your "insufficient memory" problem.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I indeed conflated RAM and app storage a bit. I should probably edit the question.

Comment: I have used Opera before, mainly on desktop. I had it on my phone as well, but ditched to make room. But yesterday, I ditched Chrome and installed Opera instead. More space. Opera is smaller and _can be moved to secondary storage_, leaving room in primary app storage.

Comment: ahh, thats good :)

Comment: Bonus awarded to you because your answer helped me the most.

Answer (score 0):

In dealing with the limited 8GB of RAM in my Samsung Tab 4 7.0 disk space used by app data, caches, downloads, et al, affects the RAM/internal memory available to run programs(apps) and even the OS itself. I may have some of the official names and labels wrong but the bottom line is that the Windows model of internal RAM, hard drive space and virtual RAM does not exactly apply to the Android OS as there is no physical hard drive

Settings|General|Store|Device Memory lists:
Total space 8GB
System memory@ 3.28GB
Used space 4.14GB
Cached data 11.46MB
Misc files 125MB
Available  space 460MB

Under Settings|General|Application Manager it lists:
Device memory 4.3GB used / 469MB free
RAM 1.0GB used / 230-290MB free@@

@ "The minimum amount of storage space required to run the system"
@@ The numbers varied as I switched between apps and the screens in Setting while composing this post in Evernote

In any case I definitely wish that we could delete the huge Internet cache in Chrome without deleting our personal settings and passwords. :-(

I will try the Incognito mode in Chrome 46.x.x (I run older versions of Chrome which work fine with KitKat.)

sssteeve

P.S. All of this is based on my own observations in dealing with the limited RAM on my Samsung tablet. I dl a lot, saving articles, etc., so I am *always* freeing up disk space just to avoid those nasty messages about having insufficient space available. :-(

Answer (score -1):

It turns out that all of the data Chrome stores is actually the Internet Cache. If you look at the Desktop counterpart of Chrome it regularly stores ~100+ MB of Internet Cache.

**I have done some experiments**:
I have cleared the cache and ran chrome without browsing to any sites: Just started it
It did not grow very big ~5MB or less.

*BUT* when I did browse to sites got big very fast. I have a Nexus 7 v1 and a ZTE 665c and both replicated the same results.

This is typical of Google Chrome and the Internet cache. What I would recommend to you is getting a better Storage medium *if you can*. If not then I would recommend to browse in private mode because it keeps the internet cache to a minimum.

Here is some interesting facts on what is deleted. I know that is for the desktop version but most of it applies to the mobile version.
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95582?hl=en

*And as `Dan Hulme` Said it also stores this data:
It also contains:*

> - Resource files for Chrome itself. These are really part of the app,    but they're downloaded by Chrome itself so the APK doesn't need to
>     contain all the resources for all locales, and to make them easier to 
>     update.
> - Local storage for websites that use the HTML5 local storage    feature. For some sites (e.g. Twitter) this can get quite large.
> - All    your preferences, just like any other app. This amounts to a few KB.

To wrap it all up the main offender is the internet cache. The websites that you visit also give you extra files as stated above and last but not liest are the settings. The give you only a few KBs but it all adds up!

Have a great day!

Comment: Don't paste other people's answers into your answer. That doesn't add anything to the site.

Comment: But the other answer had relevant information. If I didn't include his then I would be missing information from my answer!

Comment: @DanHulme Your answer is valuable and I had more to add to it!