# I get an application error 919 when updating Chrome. How to proceed?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.1-jelly-bean, updates, chrome-for-android, system-error

While updating Chrome, I repeatedly get the following error:

```
Unknown error code during application install: "919"
```

This is on a Wolfgang AT-AS43D4, running stock 4.1.2. I have about 100 MB free space in my app storage.

This happens both on WiFi and on 3G, so the top answer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56258/51314) is not applicable.

Comment: Please note that the most likely duplicate has no accepted answer and that the top answer to it is **not applicable** here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [cache cleaner](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.cache), I freed up some cache, netting me a little over 130 MB free space in the app storage.

I then updated, and it worked. Freeing the cache *again* after the update, I only had 100 MB left. I also saw that the cache for the Play Store was about 28 MB, so apparently that's the size of the download for the Chrome update.

Using a [disk analyzer](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.diskusage), I found out that Chrome (after the update) uses over 100 MB for the apk (103.5 MB).

---

What I think happened, is that it downloaded about 28 MB, then unpacked that to 103 MB, then *replaced* the existing apk with that. So I needed 28 MB + 103 MB = 131 MB to do the update.

To be honest, I think that's quite a lot. I'm not sure if I'll be able to do the next one.
Also, as noted in [my other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/64566/51314), Chrome uses quite a lot of data as well. It was at 25 MB when I asked that question, it's now a whopping 28 MB. I have no idea what's in there and no clue how to clean that other than deleting it *all*, which probably isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Even I get same error when I have slower internet speeds. Probably slow internet is the mere problem.