# Chrome user data taking up lot of space

Tags: chrome-for-android, disk-drive

Chrome in my redmi note 4 is taking up a lot of space. I tried clearing cookies, site data, cache and browsing history. How can i access this storage without root?

Edit : i've attached the screenshot of my apps settings page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open Chrome and open Settings -> Site Settings -> Storage. There you see the list of sited and their cached storage size.

Comment: @robert thats just 15 kb.

Comment: Is the screenshot from a built-in app or is it a third party app? If it is a third party app it can only show the info from Android package manager. Check Android settings -> apps -> Chrome for the displayed storage size.

Comment: Related: [What's in Chrome's data?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/64566/whats-in-chromes-data?rq=1). Though from the structure (there's DCIM), this looks like on "external" storage? If so, then it's possible to browse without root access, unless I was tricked with the "Storage card" on the root path...

Comment: @Andrew, the entire disk space is composed of internal memory. And the question tagged by you doesn't seem relevant.

Comment: @robert, check my question again. I've attached a screenshot of app settings.

Comment: If it's in the internal memory and the device is not rooted, then the last thing you can try is to "clear data" since you can't browse it without root.

Comment: @Jai I agree with Andrew, this looks more like sdcard storage. Check `/sdcard/Android/data/com.android.chrome` and subdirectories in a file manager app, adb or MTP.